# Неправильная верстка боковой панели

Tags: дефект, дизайн

При редактировании вопроса заметил такие неприятные моменты с версткой. При прокрутке боковой панель подпрыгывает, то в начало, то в конец, а при прокрутке на самую вниз вообще закрывет footer.
Вот собственно [так](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Z2fWDPo0o98ere9haj1I9pW5YAtdP-r/view?usp=sharing) оно выглядит. И да гифка большая (12мб) и я никак не смог впихнуть её  как изображение для прямого показа. Поправьте если сможете.

Comment: Вроде нормально выглядит - мне кажется, так и должно быть.